# \DeclareSourcemap filter by \perrefsection

Tags: biblatex, biber

Is it possible to filter within a DeclareSourceMap a specific refsection, just like the filename?

I would like to use the same bib-file in two refsection. While the first refsection contains the "normal" entries, cited with \cite{}, the second refsection contains a nocite{*} command and the bibliography shows all off my own publication.

Now i ran in some problems with tex capacity errors, because the bbl files got too big. Therefore, I would like to have a DeclareSourceMap filter, where i can filter out all entry without my name, but only at the second refsection.

By now, my workaround is symlink the file to another name and use the \perdatasource switch, but the better solution would be to directly filter by refsection.

I have also opened an issue at the [github-issue-tracker](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/130), but there i got the advice to post here to find a solution.

Here is a MWE for the problem:

```
% % Konfiguration für Texstudio (Version > 2.9)
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !BIB program = biber
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX root = 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@book{goossens95,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "Another dummy entry",
    year      = "1995",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcommand{\lastname}{Goossens}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{filteredauthor}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{biblatex}{2016/03/01}
{ %New Syntax for declareindexname for biblatex>3.3
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{Filterauthor}{% Test could be refined
    \nameparts{#1} 
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\lastname}{\namepartfamily}}}
    {\addtocategory{filteredauthor}{\thefield{entrykey}}}{}}}
{ %Old Syntax for biblatex<3.3
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{Filterauthor}{% Test could be refined
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstring{\lastname}{#1}}}
    {\addtocategory{filteredauthor}{\thefield{entrykey}}}{}}
}
\makeatother

\AtDataInput{%Filter for last name
    \indexnames[Filterauthor][1-100]{author}%Test auf alle 
}
\begin{document}
\section{The normal document}
Normal document with a cite \cite{greenwade93} and another cite \cite{goossens95}.
\printbibliography

\section{Later...}
Later in the document there should be a list of all publications from Goossens only.
\begin{refsection}[\jobname.bib]
\nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[title={Publications of Goossens},category=filteredauthor]

\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

The real problem you can find after running biber at the .bbl file: The cited entries are two times in the file, because they  are triggered by the nocite command. This is not really a problem for this example, but it will be for huge bibfiles.
This problem could easily be solved, if it would be possible to filter with declaresourcemap only for refsection 1

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: Mhh, since technically this is currently not possible we could only offer an alternative solution that (maybe) does what you need - not what you ask for in the title. So it would be nice to know more about the situation where the problem occurs. Could you provide an MWE that illustrates the problem? Maybe we can find a different way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible with biblatex 3.5/biber 2.6 currently in DEV on Sourceforge. There is a `refsection` option on the `\map` command in sourcemaps which forces the contained map steps to apply only to a particular reference section.