# abbreviate journal title in \fullcite command

Tags: biblatex

I have a bibliography with lots of journal articles from a small number of journals. I want to abbreviate the journal title but only when it occurs in a `\fullcite` command: I want the full journal title in the References list.  How can I do that?  A solution which cites all the entries in the bib file won't work, as it contains lots of entries I don't want to show. The following code abbreviates the journal title in both situations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{art,
    Author = {Author, A},
    Year = 2006,
    Journal = {A Journal With a Long Title},
    Number = 1,
    Pages = {1-10},
    Title = {An Article}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
 \DeclareSourcemap{
   \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journal,
            match=\regexp{A\sJournal\sWith\sa\sLong\sTitle},
            replace={Journ}]
    }
   }
 }
\begin{document}
\fullcite{art}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it this way: First, modify your Sourcemapping slightly:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journal,
        match=\regexp{A\sJournal\sWith\sa\sLong\sTitle},
        fieldset=shortjournal, fieldvalue={Journ}
        % replace={Journ}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Next, create a boolean switch:

```
\providebool{use:shortjournal}
```

Then, redefine the `journal` bibmacro (taken from `biblatex.def`) to incorporate the boolean. However, because this creates a degree of nesting and repetition, it is better to redefine the original macro in terms of some new bibmacros.  That is, take the original definition:

```
% Original definition (from biblatex.def)
% \newbibmacro*{journal}{%
%   \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
%     {}
%     {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
%        \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
%        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
%        \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}
```

And reformulate it so it looks like this:

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifbool{use:shortjournal}%
    {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}%
      {\usebibmacro{origjournal}}%
      {\usebibmacro{shortjournal}}%
    }%
    {\usebibmacro{origjournal}}%
}
```

This relies on the  `shortjournal` and `origjournal` bibmacros (where `orig` signifies I'm just recyling the original `journal` bibmacro):

```
\newbibmacro*{shortjournal}{%
  \printtext[journaltitle]{%
         \printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}%
         \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
         \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{origjournal}{%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
      {}
      {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}%
}
```

Then, finally, add the boolean switch for `\fullcite`. (Note the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`: they are needed if this is going directly in a `.tex` file.)

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
  \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
      \booltrue{use:shortjournal}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:parens}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:volseen}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:titleinauthpos}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:editorinauthpos}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:in}%
      \global\let\blx@related@loop\@empty}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\boolfalse{use:shortjournal}%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
\makeatother
```

Putting it all together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{art,
    Author = {Author, A},
    Year = 2006,
    Journal = {A Journal With a Long Title},
    Number = 1,
    Pages = {1-10},
    Title = {An Article}
}

@article{art2,
    Author = {Author, A},
    Year = 2006,
    Journal = {A Journal With a Non-Matching Long Title},
    Number = 1,
    Pages = {1-10},
    Title = {An Article}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Step 1.
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journal,
        match=\regexp{A\sJournal\sWith\sa\sLong\sTitle},
        fieldset=shortjournal, fieldvalue={Journ}
        % replace={Journ}
      ]
    }
  }
}

% Step 2.
\providebool{use:shortjournal}

% Step 3.
% Original definition (from biblatex.def)
% \newbibmacro*{journal}{%
%   \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
%     {}
%     {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
%        \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
%        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
%        \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}


\newbibmacro*{shortjournal}{%
  \printtext[journaltitle]{%
         \printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}%
         \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
         \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{origjournal}{%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
      {}
      {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}%
}


\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifbool{use:shortjournal}%
    {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}%
      {\usebibmacro{origjournal}}%
      {\usebibmacro{shortjournal}}%
    }%
    {\usebibmacro{origjournal}}%
}

% Step 4.
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
  \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
      \booltrue{use:shortjournal}%          <-- the added line
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:parens}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:volseen}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:titleinauthpos}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:editorinauthpos}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:in}%
      \global\let\blx@related@loop\@empty}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\fullcite{art}\par
\fullcite{art2}\par

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: shortjournal.png]

Comment: Of course, rather than do a complicated Sourcemap, it may be faster to simply add the `shortjournal` field into your `.bib` directly (depending on how many entries there are).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this trick is OK for you, but put the whole document under a fake refsection and add `[refsection=1]` in `map` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

% Declare an ad hoc category
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{quack} 

% Renew fullcite command
\let\oldfullcite\fullcite % this in necessary to renew the command with the same name
\renewcommand*{\fullcite}[2][]{\addtocategory{quack}{#2}\oldfullcite[#1]{#2}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{art,
        Author = {Author, A},
        Year = 2006,
        Journal = {A Journal With a Long Title},
        Number = 1,
        Pages = {1-10},
        Title = {An Article}
    }
     @article{noinbib,
        Author = {Buthor, A},
        Year = 2006,
        Journal = {A Journal With a Long Title},
        Number = 1,
        Pages = {1-10},
        Title = {An Article that should not be listed in bibliography}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
        \map[refsection=1]{% with refsection=<n> the map is valid only for the refsection with <n> number
            \step[fieldsource=journal,
            match=\regexp{A\sJournal\sWith\sa\sLong\sTitle},
            replace={Journ}]
        }
    }
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
   \begin{refsection}% fake refsection
       %\therefsection % use this to discover the number of the refsection
    \section{Title 1}
    A citation: \fullcite{art}
    some text
    \section{Title 2}
    Some other text and
    another citation: \fullcite{art}

    \end{refsection}

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[category=quack] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = It works only with recent versions of `biblatex`/`biber` packages, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316682/declaresourcemap-filter-by-perrefsection).

EDIT: I've updated the answer according to what you required in your comment.

I've created an *ad hoc* category in order to list only the cited references (not all references in the `.bib` file) in the final bibliography.

Note that if some kind of citation other than `fullcite` is used, the relative command has to be analogously renewed.

Comment: Excellent.  And if I omit `\nocite{*}` and do `\printbibliography[section=1]` then the
bibliography contains only cited sources, not everything in the bib file.

Comment: Spoke a bit too soon... if I do that, then the journal title appears in appreviated form in the final references list. So, is there a way I can repeat all cited references (not all references in the bib file) in the final list of references?